# How do I get 10 ordered entries inside a view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my Model Movies and that has a property called Rating (calculated average), I'm trying to get the 10 highest rated entries out of that model from within a View. I already have the model defined within the view and can access it but I am lost from there on.
Furthermore I was wondering whether it would be possible to get the ratings assocaited with said 10 entries afterwards.

Comment: How can we help without seeing some code ?

Comment: What code do you need exactly? The View is empty besides the model definition and some html tags. I was wondering if there was some kind of method that applies in this case that lets me run a query or something.

Comment: Yes, there is. Look for entity framework documentation, which will answer your question better than a short answer here (which would be vague anyway, as the question is too broad and lacks specific details).

Comment: How is the question vague, I'm trying to get 10 elements ordered by a property (descending) inside a View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first order your list by Rating and after take the first 10 elements.
I'm assuming that your model contains a list of movies, and the Movie object has a Rating property. If this is the case, your code should look like this:

```
var yourList=Model.MovieList.OrderBy(x=>x.Rating).Take(10);
```

Comment: I can't use var inside a View.

Comment: @var yourList=Model.MovieList.OrderBy(x=>x.Rating).Take(10); Try it with @ at the beginning

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6us6kw

Comment: then put the code like this @{ //the code here }

Answer (score 0):

i don't know, but maybe this help your:

```
var list = yourQuery.Take(10);
```

this take first 10 elements

Comment: I can't use var inside a View.

Comment: @user1826176 SimonaB answered for your question